# Joining SQL Database Table with Excel Sheet Data Using Power Query

Tags: sql, excel, database, join, powerquery

I'm accessing a table in a SQL database through Excel Power Query and I want to do a join with some data that I have in a excel sheet. I don't have write access to the database so I'm not able to just create a table with the Excel data there.

Is there a good workaround that would allow me to join the database table with the data in the Excel sheet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you load the data from the SQL database in a query you can merge it with another query in the power query editor. You just have to navigate to the power query editor and find the merge button.
[image]

The editor will ask which are the two queries you want to merge and to indicate which columns contain the matching data.
Several types of join are supported.

[image]